Are there any options for druid damage caster to get anywhere near Fireball Trick damage?
Looking for a way (spells, feats and features to compliment/boost those spells) to make druid at least half as good at damaging enemies with spells as Fireball Trick sorcerer is.
Context: level 14, mythic 3, full RAW (including unrestricted crafting and fully customized cohorts, like secondary PC's effectively).
I consider it a success if such druid will be able to deal half as much damage as sorcerer (currently roughly 50d6+50 so let's say half is 25d6+25). I'm not including quicken, empower and maximize in both cases, because those feats are equal on both sides of comparison and will be used regardless.

For reference’s sake, 50d6+50 averages 225 damage, so the goal here is to beat 112½ average/expected damage. However, I do have to ask: fireball has a long range and hits a large area, but allows a saving throw. Do these factors have to be considered, or are we only concerned with the average damage?

Do you mean one of these tricks? https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/magic-trick-2/#fireball_tricks ? Which one?

Just the maximum possible damage rather. Maximize and Quicken will be used anyway, Empower possibly too. Via some combination of Sacred Geometry, Rods and Mythic Archmage ability that's equivalent of Quicken.

They stack Molot, Cluster and Scatter are the basis for Fireball Trick builds, alongside metamagic discount traits. The 50d6+50 is an estimation that already counted those tricks and Archmage Path Ability and Bloodline. I didn't count Empower, Maximize and Quicken though, because both sorc and druid will use those identically obviously.

As a baseline, let's invoke the idea that imitation is the sincerest form of flattery.
Druids can obtain access to Fireball via taking the Fire domain or, if your GM allows for an interesting definition of nature deity, the Dreamed Secrets feat. From there, we can take Magic Trick (fireball) as normal and combine the cluster and concentrated tricks to get 1.5 damage dice per CL where basically everything else only gives 1 die per CL. Current status: 21d6+0, CL 15.
We can replicate a Bloodline Arcana providing +1 damage per die with the Flumefire Rage feat, and both its generic prerequisites are useful for our purpose as well: Varisian Tattoo increases our CL, and Spell Focus increases our save DC. I'm not sure whether the damage increase from Flumefire Rage counts as a "set numerical bonus" for Spell Perfection, but the CL increase from Varisian Tattoo definitely does. Current status: most conservative 24d6+24, CL 17; most generous 24d6+48, CL 17.
Finally, we look at other ways of boosting CL. The easiest ways appear to be with an Orange Prism ioun stone for +1, and having your cohort buff you with the Eldritch Aid feat (though this is likely unreliable depending on how modified spell levels are interpreted). Current status: most conservative 27d6+27, CL 18; most generous 33d6+66, CL 22.
Including the three metamagic feats for Spell Perfection (one of which also qualifies for the concentrated fire trick), this comes out to 9 feats, obtainable by a level 15 human without any additional feat slots (this includes leaving both your mythic feat slots open). Side effects may include tiredness (from Flumefire Rage) and insanity (from Dreamed Secrets).
It is worth noting that, while these options allow a Druid to meet the stated benchmark, they aren't exclusive to the Druid class, so a Sorcerer could use them to widen the damage gap as well. This approach plus a bloodline arcana and Blood Havoc allows the sorcerer to hit 27d6+81 (or 33d6+132) without any mythic material.

That's a valid example but not what we're looking for. We already have fireball sorcerer in group and the whole point is for druid to feel unique while still being able to deal competitive damage, not for him to feel like a cheap copy of our sorcerer.

It's janky and clunky, but Fungal Blisters can do incredible damage through the power of quadratic damage scaling.
(1d2 + 1) x (1d6 + 1) x (CL / 2)², which at CL 14 with no modifiers averages 551 damage, which is an equivalent average to 122d6 + 122.
This of course necessitates a way to quickly don heavy armor to detonate the spores all at once, such as reverting from Wild Shape, or a wand of Instant Armor.
It also comes with many drawbacks compared to fireball, such as being an inhaled disease effect (severely limiting what it can damage), only hitting enemies in a 5-foot radius around you, and being fully negated on Fortitude save.

Still an amazing combo. Thanks.
